# Oracle deadlock graph

Tags: oracle, concurrency, parallel-processing

We get a deadlock in one of our merge statement

```
merge into target tt using
(select * from global_tmp_tb) hh
on( hh.pk=tt.pk)
when matched then
 update
when not matched then
 insert


---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------  
process session holds waits  process session holds waits  
   2404    6309     X           2407    6502           S  
   2407    6502     X           2405    6372           S  
   2405    6372     X           1409    4103           S  
   1409    4103     X           2404    6309           S 

Rows waited on:  
  Session 6309: obj - rowid = 0033DA34 - AAM9o0ACfAAOH6cAAA  
  (dictionary objn - 3398196, file - 159, block - 3702428, slot - 0)  
  Session 6502: obj - rowid = 0033D9B0 - AAM9mwACfAAOJaXAAA  
  (dictionary objn - 3398064, file - 159, block - 3708567, slot - 0)  
  Session 6372: obj - rowid = 0033D9B0 - AAM9mwACfAAOJhzAAA  
  (dictionary objn - 3398064, file - 159, block - 3709043, slot - 0)  
  Session 4103: obj - rowid = 0033DDD0 - AAM93QACfAAOLC5AAA  
  (dictionary objn - 3399120, file - 159, block - 3715257, slot - 0)
```

It is likely that the merge insert will cause the deadlock, so let say its update

In particular, it is waiting a S lock which is a shared lock.
But if its deadlocking on update then why it is not exclusive lock ?

Also what is all these mean

```
  Session 4103: obj - rowid = 0033DDD0 - AAM93QACfAAOLC5AAA  
  (dictionary objn - 3399120, file - 159, block - 3715257, slot - 0)
```

What data dictionary object I need to query

Answer (score 1):

Locking is very complicated and I admit there's lots about it I don't understand. A `MERGE` is a combination of a `SELECT` statement (the `USING` clause) and an `INSERT` and/or an `UPDATE` statement. My guess is:

1. The share (S) locks are those sessions locking the rows in a non-exclusive mode because they've checked the table for the source data of the `MERGE` in the `USING` clause of the statement.
2. The exclusive (X) locks are for an update that's been made on the table.

So I think basically what's happening is:

1. Session A gets the source data in `global_tmp_tb` and locks the rows in share mode.
2. Session B gets the source data in `global_tmp_tb` and locks the rows in share mode. Since share mode is not exclusive, two sessions can both have a share row lock with no problem.
3. Session A updates row 1 based on the ON clause. This gets an exclusive lock on the row.
4. Session B updates row 2 based on the ON clause. This gets an exclusive lock on the row.
5. Session A tries to update row 2. It can't because session B has it locked in row-exclusive mode.
6. Session B tries to update row 1. It can't because session A has it locked in row-exclusive mode.
7. Boom, deadlock.

Do you really need to get every table in `global_tmp_tb` for all these sessions? Can you narrow down the source data for each session with a `WHERE` clause?

Could you do `select * from global_tmp_tb for update` prior to your `MERGE` to get around this? This would mean that access to the merge is serialized and each session has to go in order, which may be bad.

Comment: The issue is we are 99% sure the data is partitioned correctly which mean session-1 will only update row-1 and session-2 only update row-2

Comment: actually, when i read the graph more carefully, it seems the session is waiting on a shared lock not exclusive lock which mean its not an update/update contention. according to the above comment from the OTN forum